# Animate simple ContextMenu

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a button, which should a menu with several subitems. The menu should "slide down" or anything like that. I am trying to accomplish this using simple TranslateTransform but I am constantly getting the following runtime error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'translateTransform' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu'.`

What is the cause? Is there a way to fix that? Are there any (free) alternatives to the menu animation approach?

```
        <Button Name="Settings" Margin="2" Style="{StaticResource GrayGrayButtonStyle}">
            <Image Source="gear.png" />
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 0"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 1"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 2"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 3"/>
                    <ContextMenu.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform"
                            X="{Binding 
                                Path=ActualWidth, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                                FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
                    </ContextMenu.RenderTransform>
                    <ContextMenu.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContextMenu.Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="translateTransform"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                         To="0"
                                         BeginTime="0:0:3.5"
                                         AutoReverse="False"
                                         Duration="0:0:2.5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ContextMenu.Triggers>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what exactly you're going to achieve with that animation, but you could write it like this:

```
<DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
    To="0" ... />
```

Unfortunatly nothing will be animated! The `TranslateTransform.X` property is already 0, since its binding results in an error. You could however write your TranslateTransform declaration like this:

```
<TranslateTransform 
    X="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.ActualWidth,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

Comment: Basicaly, I need any dynamic animation when the menu is being shown.

Comment: I am probably was not clear enough in my question. As you can see my problem is that `"translateTransform"` item can not be found. Your suggestions about changing the binding would not affect the exception I experience.

Comment: And what about also changing the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` as i suggested?

Comment: Aha! I see your edit. Yes, that probably would work. Let me check it.

Comment: I can see the animation. (Not the one I supposed to see, but I will fix that myself.) Thank you.