# Need to create Listbox remove item with animation in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-8

How can i achieve that when I remove an item from the listbox it should animate when it removes. I have an observable collection that is binded to the listbox. When I delete an item from this observable collection it will be removed from the listbox also. So I want that when the item is getting removed it should animate and then get removed.

Comment: Do you mean Windows Phone 8, Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, or Windows Phone 8.1 runtime?

Comment: I mean Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Here is a good place to start:
http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/windows-phone-8-apps-development-jumpstart

Comment: I do understand that is good place to start just want something specific that can help me out to put my storyboard for the items in Listbox on removing an element from there...

Comment: @BalrajSingh Hi.. What is mean by **achieve remove an item animation on Windows Phone 8 Listbox** Do want to remove an item from Listbox.. Like this http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fres.cloudinary.com%2Fdvi6ot1t1%2Fimage%2Fupload%2Fv1406474246%2Fwp_ss_20140429_00011_hi5fgu.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Figrali.com%2F2014%2F04%2F29%2Fshow-context-menu-using-menuflyout-windows-phone-8-1%2F&h=1280&w=768&tbnid=yYyw4QEIO-ZCgM%3A&zoom=1&docid=PrM09RuUyx7bzM&ei=EA3iU9rpLcq-uATSpoJQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CCQQMygIMAg&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=1&page=1&start=0&ndsp=48

Comment: Yes I mean that when I remove an item from the listbox it should animate and then get removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer,

The control you have to use `ContextMenu`. To use this control you have to Install [NuGet Package](http://nuget.org/packages/WPToolkit/)

Add the "toolkit" prefix declaration. Make sure that your page declaration includes the "toolkit" namespace:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

After adding reference in your Listbox add items like this

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True"
                                         x:Name="ContextMenu">
                        <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Delete"
                                          Header="Watch Trailer"
                                          Click="Delete_Click" />
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                ...
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Finally, write click event code in code behind in .cs file.

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
   //Do something    
}
```

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/05/19/windows-phone-toolkit-context-menu-getting-selected-item-within-a-long-list-selector.aspx) & [Reference Using MVVM](http://igrali.com/2014/04/29/show-context-menu-using-menuflyout-windows-phone-8-1/#.U-MNRfmSzwU)

Comment: Where do i put the animation for item deletion?

Comment: Animation is predefined. When you hold on any item of your Listbox it will show popup of menu on particular item. In menu there will be a button Delete. If you click on the button Delete_click event will be raised. Take a look at this video[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tnkSD-2hmU#t=462]

Comment: No actually I want it to ad the storyboard custom into the listbox.

Comment: So.. You are looking for custom animation for ContextMenu. I didn't tried these things before. Have a look..,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482490/animate-simple-contextmenu
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076942/animate-longlistselectoritem-foreground-on-hold-in-windows-phone